# Display an image in a .rdl report that is stored in a folder within my project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, report

I need to display an image in an .rdl report within visual studio. The image need to be displayed based on a parameter (ndc number) and the images are stored in an images folder in my solution. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to embed the images as described in [How to: Embed an Image in a Report (Report Builder 3.0 and SSRS)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239319.aspx) and the tie the visibility property to an expression. Also, see the [How to create a SSRS Report with dynamic images](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/sqlreportingservices/thread/3CF1FA9C-20FB-41BF-83A8-F8B7A2B477C1) thread in the MSDN forums. People discuss a number of ways to address this there.